# Marketing Cloud Available entities to Synchronized is empty, are there any certain permission sets to be given in crm side

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, crm

When trying to set up object, no items are showing to synchronize, is that something I've missed in the configuration

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Hover over your name on the top right of the Marketing Cloud and select "Setup" from the Settings drop down.
2. Search for Salesforce Integration in the Quick Find search box or navigate to Apps > Salesforce Integration in the Platform section of the Setup menu.
3. Click Edit at the top left.
4. Click Save without making any changes.
5. Navigate back to Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronized and see there is now a data source available for synchronization.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381678&language=en_US&type=1